# Regexp - Pattern matching for multiple characters

Tags: sql, regex, hive

I need to pull upto a matching string with below combination: string starting with originMode till URBAN98D....F0F" from the string:  `version":"7.1.1","originMode":"URBAN98DC66F9-E141-408C-B6A5-99C727571F0F","ModeVersion":`

I used below regex:

```
regexp_extract(string_content ,'^.*originMode\"\:\"(URBAN+)\"',0 )
```

I am able to pull till URBAN in case if I use the expression as:

```
regexp_extract(string_content ,'^.*originMode\"\:\"URBAN',0 )
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using perl or hive or another relational database?  You should tag your question with the tool you are actually using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am using this regex in hive query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a negated character class.

```
regexp_extract(string_content ,'^.*\boriginMode\"\:\"(URBAN[^\"]*)\"',0 )
```